# How to illustrate the dynamic system output for a PID controller system?

Tags: matlab, iteration, runge-kutta, c-str

I'm trying to make a PID Controller with cstr in it for my homework in matlab environment, I've managed to come up with something promising but when I try to illustrate the x3 output, it just scrambles everything and after 26th iteration it doesn't even evaluate(bc numbers too big or small).It should control my output in a specified range with my reference, control and error signal (r(n), u(n), e(n) respectively) but i think it doesn' do that. I'm open to any help or idea. Thanks in advance.

```
clear; clc; close all;

% Initialization
Kp0 = 1.5;

Ki0 = 0.1;

Kd0 = 0.25;

u=0:1;

% CSTR system parameters
Ts = 0.1;
Da1 = 3;
Da2 = 0.5;
Da3 = 1;

x1(1:5) = 0.5;
x2(1:5) = 0.5;
x3(1:5) = 1.5;

d2 = 1;

t = 1:20;
r = 0.45 + 0.15*sin(2*pi*(1/200)*t);

for n = 3:length(r)
    % Compute error
    e(n) = r(n) - x3(n);
     
    % Update PID gains
    Kp(n+1) = Kp0 + e(n);
    Ki(n+1) = Ki0 + e(n);
    Kd(n+1) = Kd0 + e(n);

    % PID Control Signal
    u(n) = u(n-1) + Kp(n) * (e(n) - e(n-1)) + Ki(n) * e(n) + Kd(n) * (e(n) - 2*e(n-1) + e(n-2));
    
    % Saturate Control Signal
    if u(n) > max(u)
        u(n) = max(u);
    elseif u(n) < min(u)
        u(n) = min(u);
    end
    
    % Apply u to CSTR system
    k1x1 = Ts*f1_func(x1(n), x2(n));
    k1x2 = Ts*f2_func(x1(n), x2(n), d2, u(n));
    k1x3 = Ts*f3_func(x2(n), x3(n), d2);

    k2x1 = Ts*f1_func(x1(n) + k1x1/2, x2(n) + k1x2/2);
    k2x2 = Ts*f2_func(x1(n) + k1x1/2, x2(n) + k1x2/2, d2, u(n));
    k2x3 = Ts*f3_func(x2(n) + k1x2/2, x3(n) + k1x3/2, d2);

    k3x1 = Ts*f1_func(x1(n) + k2x1/2, x2(n) + k2x2/2);
    k3x2 = Ts*f2_func(x1(n) + k2x1/2, x2(n) + k2x2/2, d2, u(n));
    k3x3 = Ts*f3_func(x2(n) + k2x2/2, x3(n) + k2x3/2, d2);

    k4x1 = Ts*f1_func(x1(n) + k3x1, x2(n) + k3x2);
    k4x2 = Ts*f2_func(x1(n) + k3x1, x2(n) + k3x2, d2, u(n));
    k4x3 = Ts*f3_func(x2(n) + k3x2, x3(n) + k3x3, d2);

    x1(n + 1) = x1(n) + 1/6 * (k1x1 + 2*k2x1 + 2*k3x1 + k4x1);
    x2(n + 1) = x2(n) + 1/6 * (k1x2 + 2*k2x2 + 2*k3x2 + k4x2);
    x3(n + 1) = x3(n) + 1/6 * (k1x3 + 2*k2x3 + 2*k3x3 + k4x3);
   

    % Plotting
    figure(1);

    subplot(3,1,1);
    plot(x3, 'r');
    title('x3 - r');

    subplot(3,1,2);
    plot(r);

end
```

[Pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUVhF.png)

[What I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccRDL.png)

I try to illustrate the x3 output, it just scrambles everything and after 26th iteration it doesn't even evaluate(bc numbers too big or small).

Comment: Please do not post repeat, identical questions. You can edit your original question if you want to add details. It scrambles everything" is not a clear problem statement, did you [debug your code](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to see what's happening at each iteration? You might find it useful to read [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) because nobody here is just going to do your homework for you

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't asked the same question. As I told you before I've encountered an indexing error first, I did solve that thanks to you and others, this is the final form of my code and my problem now is about controlling my output with control, reference and error signals.

Comment: OK I've re-opened the question, but note that it's not really a good way to complete your homework (and you'll see limited success here) by posting very similar questions here each time you hit an error without trying to solve it yourself. There were less than 20 mins between you saying the previous bug was solved and you posting a new question with the next bug - my recommendation to read about how best to ask homework questions stands, as well as a read of [ask] and the [tour]

Comment: yes and there were 8 hours between your answer to that question and my second question